# Use find exec with sed to replace part of file name and copy it

Tags: bash, sed, find, exec

I have some settings file which need to go to appropriate location.
eg. settings.location1, settings.location2, settings.location3 which need to go to the appropriate folders namely location1, location2 and location3 and be renamed as simple settings.

eg.

/some/path/settings.location1 -> /other/path/location1/settings

/some/path/settings.location2 -> /other/path/location2/settings

I came up with the following comand:

```
find /some/path/settings.* -exec cp {} /other/path/$(echo {} | sed 's/.*\.//')/settings \;
```

But for some reason the sed does not get executed. And the result is

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/other/path//some/path/settings.location1/settings': No such file or director
```

It seems that if I run them separately all commands get executed well, but not if I put in exec. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, does /other/path/some/path already exist? Otherwise cp won't create intermediate folder to complete the path. Also: consider that the result of find is the full path, not the filename only.

Comment: Hi Francesco, no that does not exists, but the whole point is it's supposed to generate the destination as /other/path/location1/settings, not to put the whole "/some/path" there. And /other/path/location1 exists.

Comment: Your `$(echo ...)` is executing *once* when the `find` command is run. You want it run once for each `{}` value but that's not happening. To do that you'd need to force a shell as the `-exec`'d command.

Comment: Does [`rename 's/settings(.*)/\1\/settings/' /some/path/settings.*`](http://man.cx/prename) work for you?

Comment: @anishsane I need to move the settings.locationx in folder locationx and rename them as settings, the problem is with the move to the folder that has the same name as the extension

Comment: @EtanReisner `find /some/path/settings.* -exec sh -c 'cp {} /other/path/$(echo {} | sed 's/.*\.//')/settings' \;)` this returns nothing from `$()` and ends up dumping all sttings directly in /other/path/settings. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Right idea except for two things. I think `-exec` only replaces *one* instance of `{}` in the command (but I'd have to check that to be sure) and you should **never** expand `{}` literally in a `sh -c` command like that (it isn't safe) you should pass the `{}` as an argument to `sh` and use the positional parameters instead (i.e. `sh -c 'echo "$1"' - {}`).

Comment: @teapothat, so does my `rename` based solution/logic work for you?

Comment: @anishsane it tries to copy into .location1 instead of location1. I am still trying some stuff with that.

Comment: My bad... Try: `rename 's/settings.(.*)/\1\/settings/' /some/path/settings.*`

Answer (score 0):

to make this work you need to create the intermediate folder when they are not present in the file system.

You can try:

```
find /some/path/settings.* -exec mkdir -p /other/path/$(ls -m1 {})/ && cp {} /other/path/$(ls -m1 {})/settings \;
```

Comment: Hi Francesco, the folders location1 and location2 already exist. I just need to match the settings.location1 to location1 folder. and also in this case I need just the part after the . ls -m1 as I understand gives you the whole filename?

Comment: Why do you need `ls`?

Comment: Yes @teapothat the ls -m1 get the filename only (settings.* in your case). The direcroty will be created if not existent (-p) and the file copied over the newly created folder.

Comment: @FrancescoGualazzi Hi, thanks for the answer, but the problem is not that the directory does not exist, it is there created previously by a different script. But that the correct path is not generated. And the folders do not have the same name as the file, but as the extension of the file. So ls -m1 would not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing a very simple shell script which modified its parameters and did the operation, then having `find` do an `exec` on that script, passing `{}` multiple times.

In terms of your action, I think it would be something like:

```bash
find /some/path/settings.* -exec /bin/bash -c 'cp "$0"              \
  /other/path/"${1:s^/some/path/settings.^^}"/settings' {} {} \;
```

N.B. I inserted a line break after `"$1"` for ease of reading, but this should all be on one line. And I added double quotes around paths in case there are spaces in your paths. You might not need that precaution.

The [Bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) says,

> `-c` If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, the first  argument is  assigned  to  `$0`  and  any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to `$0` sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

The contents of the `-exec` script are: the bash interpreter path, the `-c` option, a quoted argument, find's path `{}`, then find's path `{}` again.

The quoted argument contains the shell script. Bash sets the next two arguments to `$0` and `$1`, then runs the shell script. The script uses history substitution `${1:s^/some/path/settings.^^}` to modify the path from find to keep only the part you need.